# Adnroid Jsoup получить полную версию сайта

Tags: android, jsoup

Загружаю страницу

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

У сайта есть 2 версии, обычная и мобильная, как получить полную версию, а не мобильную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
      .referrer("http://www.google.com")
      .get();
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right)

Comment: Я это пробовал, результата нет

Comment: Я извиняюсь, пробовал этот код не в том месте, ваш ответ верный, спасибо